# The definition of essential spectrum for general closed operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

I've asked this problem in MSE several days ago, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382584/prove-the-discrete-spectrum-of-a-equals-to-the-set-of-those-complex-lambda). But there is no reply up until now. Maybe I wrote things too complicated there and so I'll write a very clean problem here. For background intuitions and the long story behind the problem, interested people can read the original [MSE problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382584/prove-the-discrete-spectrum-of-a-equals-to-the-set-of-those-complex-lambda).

> **Problem.** Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and $A$ be a densely defined closed operator from $D(A)\subset X$ to $X$. Define the discrete spectrum $\sigma_{\text{d}}(A)$ of $A$ by
> $$  \sigma_{\text{d}}(A):=\{\lambda\in\mathbb C: \lambda \text{ is an isolated eigenvalue of }\ A \text{ and has finite algebraic multiplicity}\}.$$
> Here the algebraic multiplicity of an isolated eigenvalue $\lambda$ is defined as the dimension of the image of the Riesz projection $P_\lambda$ defined by
> $$P_\lambda=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma (z-A)^{-1}\,dz,$$
> where $\gamma$ is any simple closed curve around $\lambda$ which only contains one element of $\sigma(A)$ inside the curve. Now define
> $$\sigma_{\text{ess}}(A):=\sigma(A)\setminus\sigma_{\text{d}}(A).$$
> Show that $\sigma_{\text{ess}}(A+C)=\sigma_{\text{ess}}(A)$ for any bounded compact operator $C$ on $X$.

We usually define the essential spectrum in the above way for self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces, and then we can use Weyl's criterion to show the stability of the essential spectrum under (relatively) compact perturbations. However, for general closed operators, people usually define the essential spectrum through Fredholm or semi-Fredholm operators. I just wonder whether the essential spectrum defined analogous to self-adjoint case is stable under compact perturbations.

Any hints or useful references are welcome!

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!

Chapters 1 of Edmunds and Evans' [Spectral Theory and Differential operators][1] is (I think) easily the best reference for this kind of thing, and contains everything you could ever want to know about this :)

  [1]: https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar_url?url=https://books.google.co.uk/books%3Fhl%3Den%26lr%3D%26id%3D4npVDwAAQBAJ%26oi%3Dfnd%26pg%3DPP1%26dq%3Dspectral%2Btheory%2Band%2Bdifferential%2Boperators%26ots%3D5ArxEDqGuX%26sig%3DDp0PIIsWXlMcA7dMT59whtCrsi0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sBYSYo_BM4TyyATA16mABQ&scisig=AAGBfm1sBdwl5LwzxugaZPriyKiuytXWDQ&oi=scholarr

Comment: @DCM Thank you every much for your comment! This book helps a lot! It lists all kinds of definitions of essential spectra, wow! Recently I'm reading a paper which uses the fact that $\sigma(A)\setminus\sigma_{\text{ess}}(A)\subset\sigma_{\text{d}}(A)$, which is well known for self-adjoint operators in Hilbert spaces . The paper says that it takes the definition as $\sigma_{e3}$ in section 4 of chapter 1 of the book you mentioned. I'm looking for a proof now, which is likely not contained in this book, right? Do you know any reference for it?

Comment: Oh! Maybe $\sigma_{e5}$ is the right definition to make sure $\sigma(A)\setminus\sigma_{\text{ess}}(A)\subset\sigma_{\text{d}}(A)$, am I right?